# Roblox Functions returning is not returning my desired value

Tags: function, lua, return, roblox

I'm trying to return the player when the touched event is activated but it won't change the value and keeps it the same when it was first defined. Please help :D

```
--Server Script
////////////////////////////////////
local playerName = "Ree"
local function serverSideHit()
    game.Workspace.addTime.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        local player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if player then
            playerName = hit.Parent.Name
        end
    end)
    return playerName
end
print(serverSideHit())
////////////////////////////////////
-- Output
"Ree"
////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: When the Touched event gets fired, you can communicate that somewhere else, but you cannot return it from the Touched connection. What other code needs to know about the player name when the Touched event happens?

Comment: My plan was to use it as a double checker if they actually touched it. It would use a local side touched event and a serverside touched event, compared the names of the serverside name and local side name and if it's true active a function, and reset the variable again back to nil. Is there a better way to do this double-check system?

Comment: The general rule of thumb is to never trust the client, so if you are going to detect collisions on the server, you can trust that they happened.  Is this double checker in response to a problem you have observed?

Comment: I made the script fully into the server side. I don't know why I had it connecting to the client for no reason. But thank you Kylaaa :D